# Changing the Text of a ReactNative <Text/> component programmatically without using state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello StackOverflow Members,

I have a parent react-native component `<Cell/>` and inside it there is a child `<Text/>` component.  The child component has to be a `<Text/>` component, i can not change it to another component. See example below...

```
let renderedCell = (<Cell>
  <Text>HELLO PEOPLE</Text>
</Cell>)
```

I want to programmatically change "HELLO PEOPLE" to "Hello World" without using state via a callback. I have "inspected" the child component and i get this using `console.log(renderedCell.props.children)`...

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
  type:
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)
    render: ƒ Text(props, forwardedRef)
    displayName: "Text"
    propTypes: {ellipsizeMode: ƒ, numberOfLines: ƒ, textBreakStrategy: ƒ, …}
    __proto__: Object
  key: null
  ref: null
  props:
    style: (3) [(...), (...), (...)]
    children: "HELLO PEOPLE"
  __proto__: Object
  _owner: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: null, stateNode: Table, elementType: ƒ, …}
  _store: {validated: true}
  _self: null
  _source: {fileName: "component.js", lineNumber: 146, columnNumber: 17}
  __proto__: Object
}
```

I have tried, to change the text programmatically from "HELLO PEOPLE" to "Hello World" like this:

```
renderedCell.props.children.props.children = "Hello World"
```

but the above does not work... I have tried cloning the element and other things... All I need is to change the text inside the  component programmatically on the fly without using states from a callback.

Any suggestions?  Is this permitted?   Any other way to do it and accomplish the same?

TIA!

Comment: maybe if I can not modify it how can remove it and inject a new one programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Text** component use

`<TextInput editable={false} defaultValue={"HELLO PEOPLE"} ref={(ref)=> this.textInputRef=ref} />`

then you can directly manipulate the TextInput like this

```
if(this.textInputRef){
   this.textInputRef.setNativeProps({text:"Change Text Here"})
}
```

**Note:** You can't directly manipulate a `<Text>` because it uses an NSTextStorage and not an NSString property. If there was a way to convert a string value to an NSTextStorage value, then we could also manipulate the Text field, but to my knowledge, we can't.

Comment: thank you @Awais Rana, unfortunately I can not change it to a `<TextInput/>` component.  :(